# Setting up or reusing an ssh key on ubuntu OS

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Is there a way to reuse my existing  ssh key on one linux machine on a PC with Ubuntu OS,am trying to access gerrit on a Ubuntu OS PC and as expected ssh  connection needs to be established.

I don’t want to run generate a new ssh key with my email id as it might mess-up my current ssh connection, how to proceed forward? any inputs

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can copy your older ssh keys to the new machine.

Basically, copy your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` files to this new machine at same location, and you should be able to ssh in all right. You might need to explicitly specify the user account you want to `ssh` into like `ssh user@server`.

Also, you might want to go through more answers on [reusing ssh keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/10203/42377).

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you don't have different permissions for the id_rsa and the id_rsa.pub files compared to what the system would generate.

I transferred the keys and did not work for me.

But when I changed permissions to:

- id_rsa -> read/write by owner
- ir_rsa.pub -> read/write by owner + read by group + read by others

All worked. Previously I had extra permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me and save lot of my time.