# Connection reset by 10.0.3.13 port 22 / Error SSH

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, lxc

When I want to log in as "root" in my terminal to my SSH server (ssh root@akeneo.lxc), I can not, this message appears:

> Connection reset by 10.0.3.13 port 22

I am not an expert in System, could someone help me?

My version ubuntu: 16.04

---

After **ssh -v root@akeneo.lxc :**

> OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 debug1:
>
> Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1:
>
> /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting
>
> to akeneo.lxc [10.0.3.13] port 22. debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: identity file /home/pav/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 debug1:
>
> key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file
>
> /home/pav/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>
> file or directory debug1: identity file /home/pav/.ssh/id_dsa type
>
> -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file 
>   /home/pav/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>
> such file or directory debug1: identity file /home/pav/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>
> type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1:
>
> identity file /home/pav/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1:
>
> key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file
>
> /home/pav/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>
> file or directory debug1: identity file
>
> /home/pav/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling
>
> compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
>
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 debug1: Remote protocol
>
> version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
>
> debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3 pat OpenSSH* compat
>
> 0x04000000 debug1: Authenticating to akeneo.lxc:22 as 'root' debug1:
>
> SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent Connection reset by 10.0.3.13 port 22

Comment: Are you connecting to a machine on your local subnet or via VPN? `10.0.3.13` is a private IP inaccessible outside of a local network or VPC. Make sure you have ingress traffic over TCP port 22 allowed via firewall/security groups etc..

Comment: Try `ssh -v root@akeneo.lxc` to get more information on the error. I suspect that the ssh server requires publicKey authentication for root login. In that case you have to adapt the sshd_config of the server if you want password authentication. In case you want publicKey authentication you need to create the respective keys, as mentioned by @dcd018.

Comment: @dcd018 When i move "10.0.3.13" in my navigator, my website "akeneo" work

Comment: From the verbose output, seems like the server is expecting an RSA key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722668/setting-up-or-reusing-an-ssh-key-on-ubuntu-os

Comment: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa` will output your current private key. If one doesn't exist, you'll have to create a new key pair and transfer your public key to the server.